# How to make spring4gwt export more than 1 service?

Tags: spring, gwt, web.xml, url-pattern, spring-4-gwt

I successfully follow GWT and spring4gwt's tutorials and transform the StockWatcher's demo into a Spring(3.0) enabled service , by the following configurations :

web.xml :

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <!-- stockWatcher module is rename-to="stock" -->
    <url-pattern>/stock/spring/*</url-pattern> 
  </servlet-mapping>
```

StockPriceService.java :

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("spring/stockPriceService")
public interface StockPriceService extends RemoteService
{
  StockPrice[] getPrices(String[] symbols) throws DelistedException;
}
```

spring's app.xml :

```
<bean id="stockPriceService" class="destiny.gwt.stock.server.StockPriceServiceImpl"/>
```

Then , I want to add another Service : Chatroom.gwt.xml (rename-to="chatroom") , and hope the two services can be combined in one webapp and served by one spring4gwt instance .

This is my ChatService.java :

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("spring/chatService")
public interface ChatService extends RemoteService
{
  public boolean login(String username , String password);
}
```

spring's app.xml :

```
  <bean id="chatService"       class="destiny.gwt.chatroom.server.ChatServiceImpl"/>
  <bean id="stockPriceService" class="destiny.gwt.stock.server.StockPriceServiceImpl"/>
```

As to web.xml :

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/stock/spring/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Here comes the problem ! I don't know how to write a correct url-pattern to let springGwtRemoteServiceServlet able to simulantously listen to /stock/spring/* and /chatroom/spring/* ?

The StockWatcher module is rename-to="stock" , so each POST request will be post to URI  "/stock/..." . And Chatroom module is rename-to="chatroom" , and each POST will be post to URI "/chatroom/..." . I tried to write `/*/spring/*` , but in vain , both not work...

Answer (score 2):

The expression `/*/spring/*` is not a valid path for spring. Instead of trying to use a wildcard (`*`), you could explicitely set up another mapping:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>springGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/stock/spring/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>springGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/chatroom/spring/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/spring/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

And then:

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("../spring/chatService")
```